# Making PyCharm default to Django tests runner

Tags: django, pycharm, django-testing

I have a Django project that works perfectly with PyCharm's Django tests Run/Debug config.  For a particular project. how can I get PyCharm to default to Django test runner when clicking on a test method?

When I click on the folder, the right click menu defaults to Django tests (as desired).

[image: debug config on folder]'

When I click on a test method, the right click menu defaults to Python tests (not desirable, as my tests use Django).  How can I force this to be Django tests?

[image: test method]

[image: debug config on method]